# How to fix delayed typing on certain websites?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

When I am in Safari, typing an email or another form that has typing the resulting speed of text entry is mind numbingly slow!

I don't know what terms to search to identify the problem.

Why would it only be in an email?

Comment: Please add/link what you have tried so far. Do you access this website here also with Safari? Which email service do you use?

Comment: I find that typing on Stack Exchange is also slow from time to time - the markdown processing javascript is the cause in that case. Are you looking on alternatives for faster text entry? Or are you looking for steps to debug web javascript?

Comment: I've edited out some of the back story that doesn't impact the issue. Feel free to edit in some specifics - see [ask] for details on the site recommendations on asking a good question.

Comment: This would appear to relate to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198963/typing-lag-on-se-sites-safari too. Even in these comments, where I would assume the javascript shouldn't be getting in the way as much. I can finish a sentence & look up to see it type in the last few words in slo-mo.

Answer (score 1):

Without a list of sites that work and a list of sites that don't - here are some tips.

1. Open Activity Monitor and look at CPU and choose View menu -> All Processes (and then sort by CPU use descending). Watch this for apps that are slowing things down.
2. Open text edit and type there. - make note of what process are using CPU when you type and how fast it responds.
3. Open your webmail (or a slow forum) and repeat.
4. If there are programs taking CPU when you see the slowness, quit them.
5. If you have quit everything but Safari, restart the Mac and repeat the fast/slow.

Over time you will begin to see if the slowness is CPU - which is things you can control on the computer or if it's not the CPU that's waiting. In that case, it's the web site or network.

The pragmatic solution is to type in a local word processor and then copy/paste into the slow web application if you find the web application interface slowing you down.