# Performance problems, possibly malware?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, performance, malware

I have concerns about malware or something significantly affecting the performance of my iMac.

As you can see from the screen shot below I have updated to ***OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5***, but I did this after I started to have problems in the hope that any new security updates would help.

[image]

Additionally, I have installed ***Avast Mac Security*** and it hasn't identified anything.

Among my performance problems:

- Applications can open very slowly.
- Typing often has a very long lag before the letters or words appear on the screen.
- Searches using ***Spotlight*** take ages.
- Searches in ***Mail*** (which uses ***Spotlight***?) take ages.
- Clicking through folders in ***Finder*** can take ages for files to appear.

Very frustrating all of this.

I did have one of those ***MacKeeper*** things that locked up ***Safari*** one day but I've pretty thoroughly looked for evidence of it and can't find any.

Still, in the screenshot of my ***Activity Monitor*** below:

[image]

I consistently see the process, ***mds***, seeming to command a ridiculous amount of CPU time.  This doesn't seem normal to me.

I have additionally, cleared ***Spotlight***'s index by adding ***Macintosh HD*** to the ***Privacy*** list them removing it.  I have further put just about every folder into the ***Privacy*** list except for ***Documents*** and Mail & Messages.  In ***Spotlight***'s *Search Results*, I have unchecked everything except:

- Documents
- Folders
- Mail & Messages
- Contacts
- Bookmarks & History

and I still have all of this ***mds*** activity?

One more additional symptom, that has me concerned.  Some of my saved ***Safari*** information, like logins to innocent websites have disappeared.  Not certain if this followed the ***MacKeeper*** yuck or after the update to ***OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5***.

Also, I do have ***Time Machine*** running.  Not certain if the ***mds*** stuff has anything to do with it, but I even turned of ***Time Machine*** and I still saw all that ***mds*** activity.

Any suggestions about how to solve this problem or even how to analyze it much appreciated.

Comment: Roughly what files are shown by `sudo fs_usage -f filesys | grep mds`? This command shows what files mds (and related processes) are accessing, which should show which files are currently being indexed (mds is Spotlight indexing). Malware is extremely unlikely.

Comment: @grgarside -- Running the command shows lots and lots of things, (and it keeps running) ,but what does this mean?  What should I look for?  What can this output tell me?

Comment: Press ⌃C to stop the command so you can read it. There will be paths which should give you an idea of what it is indexing. For example, paths to files on your Time Machine drive shows that it is indexing Time Machine.

Comment: When you say *"I have updated to OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5"*, do you mean you did an incremental update, not a clean one? Doing that on top of malware is not a great idea. Better to save your data (to external SSD/ cloud/ whatever), then do a fresh install of OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters, clearing Spotlight's index will make mds have to work all the harder to refill it.

If you've ever had MacKeeper on there, you need to get hold of [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/mac/) to get rid of the leftovers.

Avast, in itself, will slow down your machine. I tried it once, got rid of it within a week.

I'd also be tempted to say updating to El Capitan might fix some of it. I found Yosemite was getting pretty laggy towards the end. I even posted on here about one aspect of it - [Typing lag on SE sites - Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198963/typing-lag-on-se-sites-safari)

Comment: But, I cleared the Spotlight index over a week ago.  Shouldn't that give it plenty of time?  I'll check out the rest of your suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, Malwarebytes found something called Spigot and removed it, but I still seem to have the problems.  I've also uninstalled Avast.  El Capitan seems like the next step... I'll keep you posted

Comment: Update to El Capitan seems to have helped and may have solved the entire issue.  You've got my vote for now.  -- Thanks.