# Macbook Air screen drawing suddenly slow

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gpu

This has been going on for a week or 2. Restarting seems to help because WindowServer is blowing up. But the problem keeps coming back.

Specs:

- Macbook Air mid-2012, 8GB RAM, 2ghz i7
- Yosemite 10.10.5
- Chrome 49

Some symptoms that recently popped up:

- Page scrolling in Chrome is laggy. Turning off GPU acceleration in Chrome fixes the problem
- Typing this question in Chrome is laggy as it updates the preview text below
- Switching tabs in Chrome is laggy
- Page scrolling in Safari is not laggy
- Switching applications in OSX (command+tab) is laggy
- WindowServer likes to consume CPU (mostly solved by disabling Little Snitch menu bar, but it's still using decent CPU from time to time)
- Activity Monitor says that WindowServer is currently using 35GB memory. (!?)

CPU usage is generally low and memory usage is currently 7GB.

Comment: WindowServer & overall memory usage would be a concern, but I had something similar on Yosemite which never went away until I updated to El Capitan - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198963/typing-lag-on-se-sites-safari

Comment: Anything logging many mesaages per second? Check your console (All Messages) to find out.

Comment: I'm confused what "memory usage" is. You say 35 GB and then you say 7 GB total. Are you looking for guidance using activity monitor/top/memory pressure? Or is this more about how to make a new user account and troubleshoot preferences and extensions/plug in? I'll pop into [chat] with [some ideas for you...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28127059#28127059)